# How to integrate epf service without any third party if public API not available

Tags: epf

I am looking to integrate epf service in my payroll application so that finance officer can directly upload the epf data to the epfo web site.

But epfo do not provide any public API to do that and I don't want to use any third party for this.

Is there any way we can do this?